# How to properly alternate the color of html row using javascript in Rails 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, html-table

I have successfully put highlighting in my table but the problem is with alternating the row color. The row color is alternating only after the row is highlighted. In 
other words, when the page is first loaded or refreshed, all the row color is colored white which is the default. I want to fix this in a way that whether its first time loading the page or it is refreshed the color is already alternating. By the way, I used a combo of JavaScrpt, and embedded ruby for this.

Here is the code fragment for my `index.html.erb`:

```
<table id="table_list">
 <tr onMouseOver="this.className='highlight'" onMouseOut="this.className='<%= cycle :odd, :even %>'">
  <td> Data 1 </td>
  <td> Data 2 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

and on my CSS:

```
<pre>
#table_list{
  border: solid 1px #666;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#table_list th{
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #404C99;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  text-align: left;
}

#table_list .highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#table_list td {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 2px 6px;
}

#table_list .even td {
  background-color: #E3E6FF;
}

#table_list .odd td {
  background-color: #D1D8F6;
}

</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use JQuery for this coloring purpose.

You might find the :even and :odd selectors useful.

You could then use them like this (Working Copy):

Your can download jquery from [jquery.com](http://jquery.com)

```
    <style>
        #table_list .even td
        {
            background-color: #E3E6FF;
        }
        #table_list .odd td
        {
            background-color: #D1D8F6;
        }
        #table_list td.hover
        {
            background-color: green !important;
        }
    </style>

    <script language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#table_list').find('tr>td').hover(function() {
                //$(this).css("background-color", "green");
                $(this).addClass('hover');
            }, function() {
                //$(this).css("background-color", "inherit");
                $(this).removeClass('hover');
            });
            $('#table_list  tr:even').addClass('even');
            $('#table_list tr:odd').addClass('odd');

        });



    </script>

    <body>
        <form id="form2">
        <div>
            <table id="table_list">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Babu
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        2
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Satheesh
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        3
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Ramesh
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        4
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Venki
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        5
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Abhishek
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the onmouseout. use the css:

```
tr:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

instead. Then in your table:

```
<table id="table_list">
  <tr class="<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">
    <td> Data 1 </td>
    <td> Data 2 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

if you want it compatible to IE(I believe :hover doesn't work on non anchor elements in IE),  you can use JS(or jquery to do the hover for you.

Answer (score 1):

Set the starting class.

```
<table id="table_list">
 <tr class='<%= cycle :even, :odd %>' onMouseOver="this.className='highlight'" onMouseOut="this.className='<%= cycle :odd, :even %>'">
  <td> Data 1 </td>
  <td> Data 2 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the same thing... I have tried that already... It turns the background-color to #D1D8F6. It doesn't alternate anymore.

Comment: I don't know the syntax of Ruby, but the premise is that you want to set the "class" equal to whatever the onmouseout is setting.  My guess is that the cycle command would now be cycling twice per row causing each row to have the same class and the same (opposite) onmouseout.  Would changing one of the cycles by switching the order correct this?  If not you might have to use a javascript solution to store the row's class before setting it to "highlight".

Comment: @johan, look at the HTML/javascript source produced and you'll know what's going on... always.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/). Assuming we want to alternate between li tags, we do the following.

```
$('#test li:nth-child(odd)').addClass('odd');
```

You can do the same for your td's or any other element.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/T4Ywt/1/

Comment: if you can use :nth-child(odd) to denote odd table rows in CSS, then you don't need to call addClass('odd'). The problem's already solved.

Answer (score 1):

@johan, the reason your code doesn't work is because the Ruby code that does the cycling between odd and even is only run *once*, when the page is loaded. If you load `index.html` and then look at the source for it in your browser you'll see something like:

```
...
 <tr onMouseOver="this.className='highlight'" onMouseOut="this.className='odd'">
...
```

Comment: Yeah.. That is what I am seeing... How am I gonna fix this? I tried the other answers but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

This task got a lot simpler with CSS3, which added the :nth-child() pseudo-selectors.

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #E3E6FF; 
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #D1D8F6; 
}
```

Now you don't need to set a class for your table rows, just to style even and odd rows separately. So no need for Rails or JQuery calls for that, and the CSS solution automatically handles changes to the table structure.